# Visualforce Page navigation issue

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have pretty long Visual force page in my application i have to requirement to save it automatically for every 60 sec seconds.So whenever i save the page the cursor goes to the top of the page instead of being where they are previously present.Can anyone give me answer on how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JavaScript Remoting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_js_remoting.htm?CSHID=pages_js_remoting.htm) instead of a apex:actionPoller. JavaScript Remoting doesn't invoke a page refresh automatically. So set up your timer in JavaScript using setInterval() and when it fires your JavaScript method, call the Apex save method that does the saving you want from there.

Comment: Thanks alot adam for the answer..and the same thing is happening with save button also.That is when filling the form i also gave them option to manually save it.So when hit the save also the entire thing gets refreshed and cursor moves to the top of the page.Any thoughts around this.

Comment: Sounds like you need to specify a rerender="componentid" in your apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" block. Without rerender, it will always refresh your entire page and reset the location to the top.

Comment: <apex:commandButton rendered="{!NOT(showAPRReportAttach)}" value="Save" action="{!saveAPR}" style="font-size:12px"/> this is my save button code i am using rendered even then this is happening